# Why does a gradient in ie8 make a link collapse so that only inner elements are clickable?

Tags: html, css, rgba

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zzxsy/1 (in ie8, maybe lower too)

at the bottom of the css are fixes to my rgba usage, however they seem to make the link shrink to its contents. Yet when i apply a border to see whats going on arround each `a` tag the border is exactly where it's supposed to be as if the link hasn't shrunk at all?

i'm very confused?

Comment: Well, the first problem is it's Internet Explorer.

Comment: i didnt know ie8 supported gradients...

Comment: well its technically a gradient filter, but yeah i guess if you make enough effort you can eventually fix up ie enough to make it presentable... i think

Comment: Use http://jsbeautifier.com/, prefix the code with `<style>`. Output of nicely formatted CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/zzxsy/1/

Comment: useful too, ive never seen it before